# How to use createAutoCorrectedDatePipe and createNumberMask feature from text-mask in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i am using this awesome vue component called [text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask), it offer a simple yet elegant solution for input mask that i use for inputting datetime format and number format. i can make it works for the most part based from documentation like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>Phone Number</label>
    <masked-input
      type="text"
      name="phone"
      class="form-control"
      v-model="phone"
      :mask="['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]"
      :guide="false"
      placeholderChar="#">
    </masked-input>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import MaskedInput from 'vue-text-mask'

  export default {
    name: 'name',

    components: {
      MaskedInput
    },

    data () {
      return {
        phone: ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

but it only offer some basic functionality and i need more like for datetime input i want to make sure maximum number for month (only 12) and for date (30 or 31 according to the month) and there is those features in text-mask that act as an [addons](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/addons/#readme)

but i can't find or understand how to make it work in vue. i tried to create an issue on the github but seeing activity on there i think my question will never be answered. so i think it is so much faster if i just ask you all in here.

Maybe there is someone who have ever been using this or maybe have other much better recomendation for input mask component that works in vue way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

- I created the "createNumberMask" function in the "data()" section of the vue component

**NumberMaskTestComponent.js file**

```
import MaskedInput from 'vue-text-mask';
import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask';

export default Vue.component('number-mask-test-component', {
    name: 'NumberMaskTestComponent',
    data () {
        return {
            numberMask: createNumberMask({
                prefix: '$',
                allowDecimal: true,
                decimalLimit: 2, 
                integerLimit: 1
            }),
            testNumber: '123.3445'
        }
    },
    components: {
        MaskedInput
    }
})
```

**NumberMaskTestComponent.vue file**

```
<template>
    <div>

        <masked-input
            type="text"
            name="numberTest"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="testNumber"
            :mask="numberMask"
            :guide="false"
            placeholderChar="#">
        </masked-input>

    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" src="./NumberMaskTestComponent.js">
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```